# PHP: Единожды генерируемое рандомное число при загрузке страницы

Tags: php, html

Ситуация такая.
На сайте при отправке контактной формы, отправляется письмо. В конце заголовка письма дописывается что то вроде номера заказа. Этот номер, как я понял генерируется простым рандомом:

```
$a9 = time() . mt_rand( 100,999 );
```

Теперь появилась необходимость, что бы это же рандомное число отображалось и на странице с благодарностью за отправку формы(воткнуть его надо среди простого HTML).
Номер каждый раз должен быть разный, но один и тот же что в заголовке письма и на странице с благодарностью.

Есть ли возможность это реализовать не перекапывая весь код? Что то вроде генерирования рандомного числа один раз за загрузку страницы?

Comment: Ну как один из вариантов: при заходе на контактную форму генерировать это число, а передавать его на сервер с помощью input hidden.

Comment: @Manitikyl Неплохая идея, но стоит задача на сколько это возможно, уже существующую структуру не переделывать.

Comment: Так особо и не нужно переделывать, просто добавьте скрытое поле, а потом выводите значение из него. Совсем без переделок не получится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php

session_id() ?: session_start();

$a9 = &$_SESSION['rand'];

!empty($a9) ?: $a9 = time() . mt_rand(100, 999);

echo $a9;
```

Comment: @Noyt я написал пример использования сессий.

Comment: Заменил `$a9 = time() . mt_rand( 100,999 );` на `session_start();
!empty($_SESSION['rand']) ?: $_SESSION['rand'] = time() . mt_rand(100, 999);
$a9 = $_SESSION['rand'];
echo $a9;`.     На тестовом сайте все работает идеально, на публичном выдает 500 ошибку. Я неправильно переделал конкретно этот кусок кода или он в порядке, но конфликтует с чем то другим в файле?

Comment: @Noyt переделано правильно, должно работать.

Comment: @Noyt попробуйте старт сессии заменить на вариант с условием: `session_id() ?: session_start();` Но я думаю, дело не в этом.

Comment: @Noyt я переписал свой ответ, попробуйте новый вариант.

Comment: Тоже самое. Вылазит это сообщение "www.название_сайта.com is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500" Может быть, что причина с .htaccess?

Comment: @Noyt ну, тогда вам надо гуглить про ошибку с кодом _HTTP ERROR 500_. Может и  с .htaccess причина, я не знаю, не сталкивался.

Answer (score 1):

После того как сгенерировали число, просто сохраните его куда-либо будь то бд или текстовый файл и потом проверяйте при новой генерации, существует ли такое, и если да, то регеним заново.

Comment: Често говоря, не очень понял о чем речь. Можно более подробно?

Comment: @Noyt вам же нужно чтобы одно число использовалось только один раз, верно? Так я и написал как можно проверять уже использованные числа.

Comment: Мне кажется ему просто нужно что бы после того как пользователь отправил форму - то же самое число показалось ему на следующей странице. @Noyt Пишите его в `$_SESSION` [почитать о сессиях](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/book.session.php)

Comment: @Asidert Не совсем. Нужно что быЧсло вызываемое через $a9 в шапке отправляемого письма и  $a9 в HTML благодарственной страницы было одно и тоже.

Comment: @Noyt это понятно, но вы же писали `Номер каждый раз должен быть разный`, про то, что оно должно быть одно и тоже для человека тоже понятно, либо шлите его вместе с формой через `POST`-запрос, либо как писал другой комментатор - через сессию

Comment: Никогда не писал ничего с $сессией, можно ли где посмотреть подходящие для этого случая примеры?

Comment: @Noyt Ссылка в моем комменте выше. Если в кратце - объявляете session_start(); и пишете что $_SESSION['a9'] = $a9;. Но лучше все же почитайте мануал, потом пригодиться.